# Unable to switch to another activity after clicking on button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

Basically I am gonna include 14 more buttons in this and all those will go to same activity with just an spinner change in the second activity. So I don't wanna create an Intent object for every button to lead to same activity(since it slows down the app). So I assigned tags to button to get the id and tried to pass that id to the new activity. But its not working. The AVD shows only the first activity and nothing happens after clicking on the button.

My main screen(Test1) activity :

```
public class Test1Activity extends Activity {


public static final String pass="com.sanjay.test1._clicked";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button1.setId(1);
button2.setId(2);

button1.setOnClickListener( new MyOnClickListener());
button2.setOnClickListener( new MyOnClickListener()); 

 }
private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
int id=v.getId();
Intent i=new Intent(Test1Activity.this,Sanjay.class); 
i.putExtra(pass, id);

}

}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Length" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Weight" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the second class(Sanjay) Activity :

```
public class Sanjay extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int a;
TextView text;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    a=getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Test1Activity.pass);

    text.setText(" "+a);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Second.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sanjay.rotation"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RotationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you created intent but not start the activity. so start activity with the intent message.  Intent i = new Intent (...); startActivity(i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add startActivity(i) in the onClick function if not the activity will never start. And you should add it into your Android Manifest too.

Like this:

```
private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
int id=v.getId();
Intent i=new Intent(Test1Activity.this,Sanjay.class); 
i.putExtra(pass, id);
startActivity(i);

}

}
```

And your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sanjay.rotation"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".RotationActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Sanjay"
    android:label="Sanjay Label">
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank You Lucia! I totally forgot about the startactivity but didn't know that I needed to include it in the Manifest also. Working Wonderfully now :D @Lucia

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity `Sanjay` needs an entry into the Manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Sanjay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using setId() to store your arbitrary data. That is the ID that is used by the system to get a reference to your Views.

View has a setTag() method that is meant for storing arbitrary data like this. You should use Tag instead of Id. like this:

```
button1.setTag(1);
button2.setTag(2);
```

and then pull them back out this way:

```
int id= (Integer)v.getTag();
```

Comment: Did you mean `int id= (Integer)v.setTag(1);` And would this also assign value '1' to the 1st button?

Comment: no, that is the getTag() not set. You won't need to pass any parameter to it. But you do need to make it {g}etTag()

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare your second activity in the android manifest. Add this inside your `<application>` tag:

```
<activity android:name=".Sanjay">
</activity>
```

As an advice keep always an eye on LogCat, in this case you would have found a warning message telling you the problem.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to use Logcat?@YuviDroid

Comment: Sure. In Eclipse, select 'Window', 'Open Perspective', 'DDMS' (if you don't find it choose 'Other..'). Then at the bottom you should see your LogCat view. Then when you select a connected device from the Devices view the LogCat will start updating and you'll see all the Log messages.

Comment: I didn't mean starting the LogCat. I meant extracting information from it. You see I am just starting with Android.Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: To extract information you have to 'manually read' the log.. You can setup some filters to ease that process (e.g. look only at warnings, errors, filter per app/tag, etc.).